# Sampling from two different normal distributions at specified probabilities

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simulation that samples from two different normal distributions at specified probabilities. I want the simulation to choose a new value from the distribution during each simulation. I created the code below, but it picks a random value on each distribution one time, and then simulates it 50 times. How can I get new values from each distribution during each iteration of the simulation?

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import normal

number_simulations = 50
P1 = normal(loc=75, scale=5)
P2 = normal(loc=25, scale=5)
elements = [P1, P2]
probabilities = [.80, .20]
simulation = np.random.choice(elements, number_simulations, p=probabilities)

print(simulation)

[26.40889965 71.60833802 71.60833802 26.40889965 71.60833802, etc]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate all 50 samples per `P` using `size`.  Then use random to choose either index 0 of `elements` (P1) or index 1 of `elements` (P2) and then call random on the resulting distribution.  You can use list comprehension to generate your 50 simulations.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import normal

number_simulations = 50
P1 = normal(loc=75, scale=5, size=number_simulations)
P2 = normal(loc=75, scale=5, size=number_simulations)

elements = [P1, P2]
probabilities = [.80, .20]
[np.random.choice(elements[np.random.choice([0,1], p=probabilities)]) for x in range(number_simulations)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit smoother would be to generate 50 samples with mean 50 and then either add or subtract 25 depending on the result:

```
import numpy as np

number_simulations = 50
probabilities = [.20, .80]
x = np.random.normal(loc = 50, scale = 5, size = number_simulations)
a = np.random.choice([-25,25], p = probabilities, size = number_simulations)
print(list(x+a))
```